# Inner Join-Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have three tables in my database. User, Employer and Jobs.

Some Users are Employers who have posted some jobs.

I am trying to display jobs by users.
My code:
User Model

```
public function jobs(){
        return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Employer','App\Job');
    }
```

Routes:

```
Route::get('/find_user_jobs',function(){
    $user=User::find(1);
    foreach($user->jobs as $job){
        echo $job->created_at."<br>";
    }
});
```

But I get this error

```
 Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'jobs.user_id' in 'field list' (SQL: select `employers`.*, `jobs`.`user_id` from `employers` inner join `jobs` on `jobs`.`id` = `employers`.`job_id` where `jobs`.`user_id` = 1)
```

I get that its trying to find user_id in jobs but here is what I want it to do

**My desire for the program**
When I give the user id, go to employers table search for user_id, if it exists ,go to jobs table and search for the employers_id and return all the jobs with the employer_id.

User Migration

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->integer('employer_id');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('users');
    }
}
```

**Job migration**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateJobsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('jobs', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('employer_id');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('jobs');
    }
}
```

**Employer Migration**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateEmployersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('employers', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('company_name');
            $table->integer('user_id');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('employers');
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post the three migrations.

Comment: Done @JonasStaudenmeir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relationship arguments are in the wrong order:

```
public function jobs(){
    return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Job', 'App\Employer');
}
```

Comment: The first argument specifies the model you want to get, the second is the intermediate model.

Answer (score 1):

Because `Employee` are `User` who have `Jobs` you can create a model `App\Employee` which extends the `App\User` Model

```
class Job {

    public function employee()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(App\Employee::class,'user_id');
    }
}
```

and Create an Employee class like this

Here in the `Employee` Model I set the `$table` property to `users`, when we make some query that query will have the target table set to `users` instead of the `employees` table which would be the default behavior of Eloquent.

```
class Employee extends User
{
    protected $table = "users";

    public function jobs()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Job::class, 'user_id');
    }
}
```

You can use directly the `Employee` Model and get `jobs`

And here are the corresponding migration

the create_user_table

```
class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{

    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->string('company_name')->nullable();
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('users');
    }
}
```

The create_job_table

```
class CreateJobsTable extends Migration
{

    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('jobs', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer("user_id")->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('jobs');
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this applies that even if I have different tables for Users and Employers.

Comment: Not working bro. new Error   Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'jobs.user_id' in 'field list' (SQL: select `users`.*, `jobs`.`user_id` from `users` inner join `jobs` on `jobs`.`id` = `users`.`job_id` where `jobs`.`user_id` = 1)

Comment: this force you to have only one table that old your User, because employee are firstly User you don't have to create a separate table to save that special kind of User, you can just extends the `User` Model like I say.

Comment: If you have to separe model why would you pass through User Model because you want to retrieve jobs for given employee?  use directly the `Employee` and pass the given ID to the `find` method